# Adding person.city.name to a TableView

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, tableview, fxml

I have a TableView and some POJOs and want to bind with a property from one of them to the TableView.

However, this property is also a POJO and this should get one property to show in the TableView.

Here's my code:

```
<TableView fx:id="listaDeudores" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Archivo">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="archivo" />
      </cellValueFactory>
      <cellFactory>
        <FormattedTableCellFactory alignment="center" />                                                
      </cellFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="299.0" text="Nombres">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="nombres" />
      </cellValueFactory>
      <cellFactory>
        <FormattedTableCellFactory alignment="center" />                                                
      </cellFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="95.0" text="Actual" >
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="deuda.saldo" />
      </cellValueFactory>
      <cellFactory>
        <FormattedTableCellFactory alignment="center" />                                                
      </cellFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Nueva" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Parcial" />
  </columns>
 </TableView>`
```

And my `Persona` and `Deuda` classes:

```
public class Persona {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer archivo;
    private String Nombres;
    private List<Recibo> recibos;
    private Deuda deuda;
}

public class Deuda {
    private Date fecha;
    private BigDecimal saldo;
    private BigDecimal nuevo;
    private BigDecimal descuento;
}
```

I want to set Person.deuda.saldo in fxml file, so I used:

```
<TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="95.0" text="Actual" >
  <cellValueFactory>
    <PropertyValueFactory property="deuda.saldo" />
  </cellValueFactory>
  <cellFactory>
    <FormattedTableCellFactory alignment="center" />                                                
  </cellFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

but this won't render anything in my TableView. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `PropertyValueFactory` to do this: you need to implement the `Callback` directly.

Put an `fx:id="actualColumn"` on the table column, inject the column into your controller with

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Persona, BigDecimal> actualColumn ;
```

and in your controller's `initialize()` method, do:

```
actualColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<BigDecimal>(cellData.getValue().getDeuda().getSaldo()));
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as correct, as that will help others who might have similar questions find the correct answer.